# What are different ways that web applications are built to handle multiple languages?

Tags: url, multilingual

I am hoping to get an understanding of all of the ways that multi-language websites/apps are built. What are pros and cons to each?  Do you have to have a separate url for each language?  If you are not using separate urls, how do you dynamically change display language?  Can you use cookies to change display language based on a drop down?

This is a pretty open ended question because I'm not very knowledgable about this and not exactly sure what targeted questions to ask.  Would greatly appreciate shared experiences and best practices for how multilanguage websites are architected.

Thanks!

Comment: In this guide, you can find a tutorial internationalizing a react application: https://locize.com/blog/how-to-internationalize-react-i18next/
In case you're not familiar with internationalization, have also a look at https://locize.com/blog/what-is-i18n/

Comment: This question is a bit too wide to be answered in full. You can, but don't have to, use different urls. You can use a cookie, or set a request header that specifies what language to use. There are often best practices depending on what web technology that is being used. If it is an SPA, for instance, then an entire dictionary might be bundled with the app, and JavaScript sets text labels at runtime as the user navigates in the browser.